# SendGrid Email API - GCP Marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I've enabled SendGrid Email API from GCP marketplace.[image]

The issue is when I'm clicking on 'Mange on Provider' button it will navigate to link somewhat like below and it throws 401 Error.
'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/public/sso/**************'

What did i miss? Please help me to resolve this!

Comment: 401 error represents authentication error. Add an Authorization header to your API request that contains an API Key for authentication. Check whether you have added the header to the API request. Refer to the [link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/how-to-use-the-sendgrid-v3-api/authentication) for more information.

Comment: Sorry you're experiencing this. The best thing you can do is get in contact with [SendGrid support](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/support) as this is not really a programming issue that we can solve on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Srividya Thanks for your response. But your answer is not suitable for me since i'm getting this while trying to login to the sendGrid.

Comment: @philnash Thanks. I'll contact support team.